# Point of declaration for an enumeration

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, declaration, c++14

What is the point of declaration of enumeration types? Is it immediately after the name of an enumeration? I saw Standard C++ 14 (n4296) §3.3.2/3:

> The point of declaration for an enumeration is immediately after the
>   identifier (if any) in either its enum-specifier (7.2) or its first
>   opaque-enum-declaration (7.2), whichever comes first

But when I try to reproduce it;

```
template <class T>
struct CL
{
    using UndType = int;
};

enum class E: CL<E>::UndType;  //error: E is undefined
```

I have got an error on all the compilers, although *enum-base* for enumeration `E` is placed after the identifier and must be visible.

Comment: I would say it is at the `;` (before `// error`) of the *opaque-enum-declaration*.

Comment: So in `CL<E>`, `E` is indeed not yet declared :(

Comment: Jarod42, but why isn't it declared yet? Standard says that it is immediately after the identifier, isn't it? I don't understand it

Comment: N4296 is the first post-c++14 draft, it contains many changes from c++14. N4140 is the closest

Comment: @Jarod42 The grammar is *enum-key attribute-specifier-seq identifier enum-base*, so the *identifier* mentioned in the quote in the OP seems to be `E` in this case, doesn't it? The `identifier` in your example is not part of the *enum-specifier*.

Comment: @bogdan, I also think so. Only "E" is placed between enum-key (which is "enum class") and enum-base (which is ": CL<E>::UndType") (attribute-specifier-seq may be omitted)

Comment: I found a defect report on that: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1482. So, in enum-base (which is ": CL<E>::UndType") enumeration E must already be declared and be an incomplete type

Comment: Good find. I guess you should answer your own question, since the currently accepted answer is incorrect / misleading in several ways. I'm surprised this issue hasn't been more widely reported, as it is present in all current compilers (even EDG in C++14 strict mode has this problem). I could only find an open issue for Clang - [bug 13917](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13917). I'm especially interested in having this reported for MSVC; if you want to report it yourself, please do, otherwise I'll file a bug on Connect.

Comment: @bogdan, Yes, you can file it to MSVC report

Comment: The following compiles fine on VC2013: `enum class E : CL< enum E >::UndType;`

Comment: @ZDF That's due to another bug in MSVC, which allows forward declarations of `enum`s, or, more precisely, allows *elaborated-type-specifiers* introduced with `enum` that don't resolve to a previously declared enumeration, which is ill-formed in the Standard ([3.4.4p2]). In other words, for MSVC, the `E` passed as a template argument to `CL` is not the same `E` declared with `enum class` in this case. It's still wrong, but it compiles due to the "two bugs cancelling each other out" effect. Clang and GCC reject this variant as well - at least they're consistent :-).

Comment: Bug report filed on MS Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2419377.

Comment: For me it works when  class enum has forward declaration.

Comment: @bogdan There is a mistake in my previous post: I should have written `enum class E : CL< enum class E >::UndType`. The Intel compiler (16.0.2.180 - 20160204) and VS2015 behave in the same way. My guess is that we failed to understand the meaning of paragraphs or we miss some information.

Comment: @ZDF Actually, that's ill-formed according to the Standard. The second `enum class E` is supposed to be an *elaborated-type-specifier*, which cannot use `enum class` for enumerations, only `enum`. The grammar snippets in [7.1.6.3] don't allow it, and there's even an example at the end that clarifies that `enum E` should be used to refer to a previously-declared `enum class E`. GCC issues a correct error message for it, but MSVC and Clang allow it; more bugs...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following;

```
enum class E : CL<E>::UndType;
```

Is not accepted as a valid declaration in some current implementations (tested clang++, g++ and MSVC). They do not accept the, as yet incomplete type `E`, in the *enum-base* `CL<E>::UndType`. The error given in the tested implementations is that `E` is *undeclared* at that point. They seem to place the point of declaration at the end of the *enum-base*, they consider it declared once it is complete.

When reading the specifications;

**§14.3.1/2 Template type arguments**

> [ Note: A template type argument may be an incomplete type (3.9). — end note ]

And

**§7.2/6 Enumeration declarations**

> An enumeration whose underlying type is fixed is an incomplete type from its point of declaration (3.3.2) to immediately after its enum-base (if any), at which point it becomes a complete type.

Does hint at it being compilable; as is the case with CRTP implementations.

I'm note sure if this (i.e. the failure to compile `enum class E : CL<E>::UndType;`) is the intention or if it was considered as a use case. From the specification, the opaque enum declaration is given some "special" treatment w.r.t. its base type and the requirement that it must be an integral type.

Presumably, the code *should be compilable* given the resolution to [CWG#1482](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1482).

---

As for current workarounds...

This;

```
enum class E; // default underlying type is int
```

Is the minimum declaration.

The opaque declaration could be either;

```
enum class E : int; // int base
```

The following would be a full definition (including enumerators);

```
enum class E : int {/*...*/};
```

Or to use the class template, another type (possibly `void`) could be used.

```
enum class E : CL<void>::UndType;
```

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum, underlying type is part of declaration. `enum class E` is just equivalent to `enum class E : int`.
And changing `UndType` to `char` even produces error [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b7463cc118c5fd6).

Comment: It's better now, but the part about the *enum-base* being "not yet complete" is still not right. It's an alias to `int`, that's all; the fact that `E` is indeed incomplete when `CL<E>` is implicitly instantiated is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @bogdan. Correct, I think that is the crux of the matter, the implementations don't see it as complete - I think I need to reword that part somehow. Maybe something like "They do not accept the, as yet incomplete `E` type in the base `CL<E>::UndType`."?

Comment: They're not complaining about it being incomplete. All the error messages I've seen report that `E` is an *undeclared identifier*. This indicates that they simply place the point of declaration after the *enum-base*, which is incorrect according to the quote in the OP.

Comment: @bogdan. Correct, I believe their error is that they only mark the type as declared once it is complete in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Now [CWG2516](https://wg21.link/cwg2516) is opened for this.

I believe it's a bug in the Standard which forbids a portable implementation of [`is_scoped_enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_scoped_enum).